# JQGrid Add Double Submiting And Loosing Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a sub grid that I'm adding values to.  The problem is that it submits the first time fine.  The second submit it goes through validation fine and then blanks out the checkbox values and submits them false.  After submitting to the server it re-fires the validation and fails this time. It seems to be double bound but not sure how on this page.

Here is the subgrid editrow:

```
$("#" + subgridTbleId).jqGrid('editGridRow', "new",
{
    addCaption: "Add Alert",
    editCaption: "Edit Alert",
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    clearAfterAdd: true,
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    recreateForm:true,
    viewPagerButtons: false,
    width: 365,
    beforeSubmit: function () {
        if ($(arguments[1].selector + " .EditTable input:checked").length === 0) {
           return [false, 'Must select an alert.']; //error
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }
});
```

The form has a textbox and 6 checkbox.
I'm using jqGrid  4.6.0, and jquery 1.11.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the declaration of the subgrid. I was binding a click event on a button in the table header.  I just needed to unbind the click event before rebinding it.